# isinstance(type, object) = True, why?

Tags: python, object, types, python-datamodel

I have an understanding that object is an instance of type and type inherits from object. So the following relationships makes sense:

```
isinstance(object, type)            # returns True, ok
issubclass(type, object)            # returns True, ok
```

I also know that isinstance(a,b) checks whether a is an instance of either b or its bases. So, the following makes sense too:

```
isinstance(type, type)              # returns True because it is translated to ....
isinstance(type, object)            # which is True
```

What I cannot follow is why do the following statements return True.

```
isinstance(type, object)            # returns True, but why?
isinstance(object, object)          # returns True, but why?
```

Let me know if you know. Thanks.

Comment: `object` is a type, and is therefore an instance of `type`. And it is also an instance of `object`, since it is an object. Welcome to Python.

Comment: Things can get confusing when you're dealing with metatypes.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, _object is a type, and is therefore an instance of type_ **Agree and same as my understanding.** _And it (object) is also an instance of object_ **Is object (class) an object, or its instance object() is an object?**

Comment: All types are objects.

Comment: In Python, *everything* is an instance of `object`. Including types, classes, functions, and lots of other things that you wouldn't expect to be objects.

Answer (score 4):

`object` is the root of the class hierarchy, so it is the ultimate parent class of *every* type, including `type` and `object`. That makes `object` its own parent class, which is one reason why you could not define `object` in Python alone; it has to be dragged kicking and screaming out of thin air by the Python implementation.

`type` is a class, and all (built-in) classes are instances of the meta class `type`. (Yes, `type` is its own metaclass.) And since `object` is the base class of `type`, therefore `type` is an instance of `object`.

Comment: What you are saying is all correct, and the same as my understanding too. But this is not an answer to my question. I know every type 'is an' object (by virtue of inheritance). My question is why type 'is an instance' of object. There are 2 kinds of relationship - 'is an' and 'is instance of'. The former is True. Why is the latter True?

Comment: Because it's an instance of `type` (`type` is its own metaclass), and like instances of anything else whose parent class is `object`, it itself is an (indirect) instance of `object`.

Comment: nice! got it. so the catch basically is **type is its own metaclass**. Dint know that. This makes sense now. Upvoted your ans. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Python is an object. By default all the objects are instance of **object** superclass so `instance(type, object` returns `True`

> **object** class is in the top of objects hierarchy. Even if **A** is direct child of  **B** (in below example) and both are indirect children of **object**.

**isinstance()** method is coded in such a way that it returns `True` if both the parameters are **object**. In other cases it checks whether first parameter is instance of second parameter or not.

Please have a look at the below code example.

```
class A:
       pass

class B(A):
        pass

a = A()
b = B()

print(isinstance (a, A)) # True
print(isinstance (b, B)) # True
print(isinstance (b, A)) # True
print(isinstance (a, B)) # False

print(isinstance (a, object)) # True
print(isinstance (b, object)) # True
print(isinstance (A, object) ) # True
print(isinstance (B, object)) # True
```

**object** is an instance of **object**.

```
print(isinstance (object, object)) # True
```

**A** is not an instance of **A**, same is for **B**.

```
print(isinstance (B, B)) # False
print(isinstance (A, A)) # False
```

The following code throws error as the second parameter should be a name of class.

```
print(isinstance (a, a)) 
"""
print(isinstance (a, a)) 
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of 
types
"""

print(isinstance (b, b)) 
"""
print(isinstance (b, b)) 
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of  
types
"""
```

So it is all about the code logic or implementation of **isinstance()** method that it returns `True` if both the pararamers are **object**.